# Object is being saved before I can set the variable. How do I get around this?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have view controller that prompts the user to enter in some location information, then click submit. When that happens, the data is thrown into a place dictionary and then geocoded through the methods `updatePlaceDictionary` and `geocode`. `[userListing saveInBackground]` then sends the object to an online database. Here is the `submit` method, which is called when the user fills in the information and clicks submit, along with the `updatePlaceDictionary` and `geocode` methods:

```
- (void)submit{
    PFObject* userListing = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"userListing"];

    [self updatePlaceDictionary]; 
    [self geocode];
    [userListing setObject:listingLocation forKey:@"location"];

    [userListing saveInBackground];
    [listings addObject:userListing];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)updatePlaceDictionary {
    [self.placeDictionary setValue:self.streetField.text forKey:@"Street"];
    [self.placeDictionary setValue:self.cityField.text forKey:@"City"];
    [self.placeDictionary setValue:self.stateField.text forKey:@"State"];
    [self.placeDictionary setValue:self.zipField.text forKey:@"ZIP"];

}

- (void)geocode{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressDictionary:self.placeDictionary completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if([placemarks count]) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
            listingLocation = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude]; 
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error");
        }
    }];    
}
```

All three methods work perfectly fine. The problem is, in the `submit` method, the line:

```
[userListing setObject:listingLocation forKey@"location"];
```

just ends up giving the key "location" a value of (0,0). This is occurring because geocode runs  asynchronously, and does not finish by the time the above line is reached. How can I have this value set AFTER geocode is finished running?

---

Answer (score 0):

You entire code here is going to have to be a little asynchronous. Your geocode method can have a block callback passed in, and call it when you are done with the geocode.

```
- (void)submit{
    PFObject* userListing = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"userListing"];

    [self updatePlaceDictionary]; 
    [self geocode:^{
        [userListing setObject:listingLocation forKey:@"location"];

        [userListing saveInBackground];
        [listings addObject:userListing];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];
}

- (void)updatePlaceDictionary {
    [self.placeDictionary setValue:self.streetField.text forKey:@"Street"];
    [self.placeDictionary setValue:self.cityField.text forKey:@"City"];
    [self.placeDictionary setValue:self.stateField.text forKey:@"State"];
    [self.placeDictionary setValue:self.zipField.text forKey:@"ZIP"];

}

- (void)geocode:(void (^)(void))callback {
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressDictionary:self.placeDictionary completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if([placemarks count]) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
            listingLocation = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude]; 

            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }

        } else {
            NSLog(@"error");
        }
    }];    
}
```